# Confused with celeryd config file and daemon file for Django in Linux

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am trying to integrate `celeryd` with djnago but i am stuck with its config file

There are three files they are talking about. I need to know what should be the contents of those files

My Celeryd executable is in `/opt/python27/bin/celeryd`

There are three file i don't know what should be their contents

1. `celeryconfig.py`
2. `/etc/default/celeryd`
3. `/etc/init.d/celeryd`

I am following this linl
http://celeryq.org/docs/cookbook/daemonizing.html
I am confused between 2 and 3 beacuse configuration is in celeryconfig.py

But in `/etc/init.d/celeryd` they have this code

```
if test -f /etc/default/celeryd; then
    . /etc/default/celeryd
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using celery with django, you should not use the celeryd executable directly.

You have to install django-celery and run the celery daemon as

> python manage.py celeryd

Also, you have to configure celery on the settings.py file opf your django project.

Get more information at http://packages.python.org/django-celery/

Comment: I tried that and its working if i use `python manage.py celeryd` but the problem is then it runs on foreground and i can't do anything else. How can i run that in background or as daemon. Also how cna i mention indjango-celeryy that i want to use MySQL as database backend with rabbitMQ. becasue i have put those in celeryconfig.py which is not used if use django-celery

Comment: All the settings that you put on celeryconfig.py go to the django settings.py file. Read the django-celery documentation to see how it is done. To put the process in the background you can use a standard init script or som tool like supervisor (http://supervisord.org/)